SSL error when trying to use TavilySearch tool from Langchain
I am following the quick start tutorial from LangGraph and I run into an SSL error when trying to use the Tarvily Search to perform API Call.
Below is the code
from langchain_community.tools.tavily_search import TavilySearchResults

tool = TavilySearchResults(max_results=2)
tools = [tool]
tool.invoke("What's a 'node' in LangGraph?")

Below is the error I get

SSLError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.tavily.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))"))

I tried a few things such as pip install--upgrade certifi and also add the api.tavily.com SSL certificate to my cacert.pem. I also increased the usage limit on my API. The error still the same.

Using os.environ[’REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE’]=‘/your/cert’
worked well for me.

Faced the same issue and solved it, the error is simply due to the lower version of the Langchain community. I, too was following the Langchain documentation, but since it is very old. Thir error remains.
Check this link and install the requirements mentioned:
https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/22445
